# Number of lines of code - SonarQube licensing

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, jenkins-groovy

With below configuration setting in Jenkinsfile(groovy) for `sonar-project.properties`:

1) `sonar.projectKey=MyProject-${BUILD_NUMBER}`

and

2) `sonar.projectName=MyProject-${BUILD_NUMBER}`

where `${BUILD_NUMBER}` is Jenkins build number

new project is created in SonarQube server for every new `${BUILD_NUMBER}`

---

1) With such naming convention, Is their an impact on licensing of SonarQube V6 in terms of lines of code coverage? if yes, Does `sonar.projectName=MyProject` & `sonar.projectKey=MyProject` naming help resolve such licensing issue?

2) Does above approach consume more memory in SonarQube database or other resources in SonarQube server?

3) How to delete all these projects at one go, in SonarQube server? if needed ..

Answer (score 0):

If you change the project key for every analysis, then each analysis will be considered as a new project, adding line of code until you reach your license limit.

It will also use more space in DB.

To delete all projects, you can go to Administration > Projects > Management (at least with SonarQube 7.7) and do a bulk delete.

Comment: This is Sonar Qube V6